# Ajax request not working when a function is added to the success option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble getting an ajax GET request (or any request for that matter) to retrieve the response. I am simply trying to return the response in an alert event:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').click(function() {
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'Get',
                url:     'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Potentials/searchRecords?authtoken=XXX&scope=crmapi&criteria=(((Potential Email:test@email.com))&selectColumns=Potentials(Potential Name)&fromIndex=1&toIndex=1',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I can get this and other similar post requests to work by taking away the function in the success option and editing the code like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').click(function() {
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'Get',
                url: 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Potentials/searchRecords?authtoken=XXXX&scope=crmapi&criteria=(((Potential Email:test@email.com))&selectColumns=Potentials(Potential Name)&fromIndex=1&toIndex=1',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: alert('success')

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why is this? And more importantly, how can I retrieve the response data and transfer it to an alert message? Any help is appreciated!

** Update:
Upon reading the first two users' responses on this question, this is what I have:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').click(function() {
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Potentials/searchRecords?authtoken=418431ea64141079860d96c85ee41916&scope=crmapi&criteria=(((Potential%20Email:test@email.com))&selectColumns=Potentials(Potential%20Name)&fromIndex=1&toIndex=1',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am able to get the error response, so I can confirm there is some kind of error. I also want to point out that I am making the request from a different domain (not crm.zoho.com) so should I be using jsonp? If so, how would I alter the code?

Comment: First of all correct your `type: 'GET'`, then focus on the first snippet that one is correct. But since you have your `dataType: 'json'`, the data arg of your success callback method will have a json object. so you will only see 'Object' in the alert if the call is a success, so try `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` to fix that. But if it is a failure then add a `fail: function(data) {}` method and do the same `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` in there.

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
success: alert('success')
```

you do NOT have a successful request, you are actually executing this function at the start of AJAX method. The `success` parameter requires a pointer to a function, and when you use `alert('success')` you are executing a function instead of providing a pointer to it.

First thing that you need to try is to update type to `GET` instead of `Get`:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'GET',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .done() function as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'Get',
            url:     'yourUrl',
            dataType: 'json',
            }

        }).done(function(result) {alert(data);}) //try adding:
          .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);})
    });
});
```

the error function will also give you some information in your console as to the status of your request.